# After factory reset I start getting error "Unfortunately, the process com.Google.process.gapps has stopped." Google play is not working, any solution?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I already tried reset apps, clear cache but manage spaces tag is not working in google play services.

Any solution?

Comment: If resetting apps and clearing cache didn't work for you, try other suggested workaround from the following links: (1) [Google Play, and the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped working](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/z5FfTHczJTQ)
(2) [Unfortunately the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped](http://techdracula.com/unfortunately-the-process-com-google-process-gapps-has-stopped-fix/)
(3)  [How to Fix error ‘com.google.process.gapps’ has stopped](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-com-google-process-gapps-has-stopped/)

Comment: thanks, I'll check these also.